How to add code to build.gradle which will be applied only under IDEA sync?
I have to add KSP generated code to the source set, but the path is different for debug and release builds.
If I add static path to build file I'll have class duplicate error at build time of opposite build variant.
How can I add code to build file which will be applied only under IDEA sync?


How can I add code to build file which will be applied only under IDEA sync?

You can do this by configuring the IDE as follows:

Find the Gradle task, or write one, which performs the action you want to take place on IDEA sync.

Then right-click on it, and choose for it to run before or after project sync. See documentation.


If it's essential to do it all via the build script then it may be possible using the IDEA plugin (though in my experience this is likely to require a bit of lower-level modification of the IDEA configuration files, if it is possible at all).

Note, however, that the Sync that IDEA performs (on project open, clicking "Reload All Gradle Project", "Load Gradle Changes" pop-up) is not a Gradle Task and its' behavior cannot be alter via Gradle build scripts.
Question refers to two types of build, though, so those should be configurable via Gradle scripts.

The behaviour of IDEA can be altered via Gradle build script using the IDEA plugin (although not necessarily easily) so it may be possible

I need plugin independent solution (
Now I can't use KSP generated types under IDEA because IDEA don't include KSP generated code into source set.

you can certainly get IDEA to recognise KSP generated code, but that's a bit of a different question.

I don't find solution for this, I have investigated a lot of questions of the others. But no one give me solution, so I have tried to find it by my self. The last point is IDE related settings is incompatible with build settings.

I'm not really sure what you're not finding a solution for anymore. If you are talking about actions on IDEA sync, then I would not worry about that until you have your project working correctly. If you are talking about separating between debug and release builds, that is a Gradle question and you need to be careful what folders you specify as what: but done correctly IDEA will be able to understand that, and recognise all the KSP generated code. Maybe you would like to ask another question and be more specific and give more of your project details so it's not so abstract.

No, IDEA doesn't understand KSP generated code. To fix it I have to add generated folder to source set. It works perfect for pure kotlin projects which doesn't separate debug and release build folders. For Android this is a problem, any explicit debug or  release source set in build file destroy oposite build.

You need to add the new code to the relevant source sets in the Gradle configuration.

Yes I have to, but I can't do it. Project configured propertly and source sets updated correcty at compile time. But AS doesn't see that code, so I see error marks in editor. I can't search code. Can't access any generated classes.

Maybe you should share the Gradle configuration you have attempted and the resultant error in a question. This would allow the possibility of reproduction, the possibility of showing you where you went wrong, and/or raising the issue with IntelliJ (being the authors of Android Studio).
